# Unity Gameobjects rendering in the wrong position on android but renders fine in editor and mac build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my 2d game objects rendering in the wrong position on android. I am building a brick breaker clone and using a script to read architecture of how each level should be built off a text file(1 is block 0 is empty space). The level render script is linked below. The issue only happens on android. In a Mac build I did, everything renders fine same as in the editor.I have tried changing my logic to use invisible gameobjects that guide where the blocks are placed but got no change. I suspect the WWW reader might be reading the file wrong but I highly doubt that. https://gist.github.com/Kalela/3a27878f7faa83f8014b0e5aaff24d15. (the script) Posting images of how it looks in the editor vs on an Android device.[How the level looks on render. The left blocks are shifted down in the android build for some reason but not in the editor or the mac build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hslyp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with how the text files were being read by the WWW class. I switched to a really awesome plugin called Better Streaming Assets which offers cross platform reading of streaming assets. After that my level rendered pretty well.